# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in **/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

Hi I just installed an extension from [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-product-from-front-end.html). At first I download it and run in my localhost, it is working just fine. But when I try to install it on server, it gave me error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in
>   **/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

This is the files related to this issue:
**Config.xml**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <NG_Product>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </NG_Product>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <ng_product>
            <class>NG_Product_Helper</class>
        </ng_product>
    </helpers>     
    <models>
        <ng_product>
            <class>NG_Product_Model</class>
        </ng_product>
    </models>     
</global>    
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <ng_product>
                <file>NG/product.xml</file>
            </ng_product>
        </updates>
    </layout>    
    <routers>
        <ng_product>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>NG_Product</module>
                <frontName>product</frontName>
            </args>
        </ng_product>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>                            
                    <ng before="Mage_Customer">NG_Product</ng>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
        <catalog> 
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <ng_product before="Mage_Product_CatalogController">NG_Product_Catalog</ng_product>    
                </modules>    
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>        
</frontend>
```

System.xml

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <ng translate="label" module="ng_product">
        <label>NG</label>
        <sort_order>2000</sort_order>
    </ng>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <ng_product translate="label" module="ng_product">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Product Configuration</label>
        <tab>ng</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <link translate="label" module="ng_product">
                <label>New Link Setting</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <enable translate="label">
                        <label>Enable</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                            
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </enable>                                              
                    <name translate="label">
                        <label>Link Name</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                            
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Enter the name of link which you want to display in my account left navigation</comment>
                    </name>                                              
                </fields>
            </link>
            <product_required_settings translate="label" module="ng_product">
                <label>Product Required Fields Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>                                             
                    <required translate="label">
                        <label>Required Fields</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_required</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Select multiple fields to make them required.</comment>
                    </required>  
                </fields>  
            </product_required_settings> 
            <product_settings translate="label" module="ng_product">
                <label>Add Product Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>                                             
                    <name translate="label">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Name' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </name>                                              
                    <sku translate="label">
                        <label>SKU</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'SKU' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </sku>                                              
                    <description translate="label">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Description' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </description>                                              
                    <short_description translate="label">
                        <label>Short Description</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Short Description' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </short_description>                                              
                    <weight translate="label">
                        <label>Weight</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Weight' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </weight>                                              
                    <status translate="label">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Status' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </status>                                              
                    <url_key translate="label">
                        <label>URL Key</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'URL Key' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </url_key>                                              
                    <visibility translate="label">
                        <label>Visibility</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Visibility' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </visibility>                                              
                    <price translate="label">
                        <label>Price</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>9</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Price' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </price>                                              
                    <tax_class translate="label">
                        <label>Tax Class</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Tax Class' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </tax_class>                                              
                    <meta_title translate="label">
                        <label>Meta Title</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>11</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Meta Title' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </meta_title>                                              
                    <meta_keyword translate="label">
                        <label>Meta Keywords</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Meta Keywords' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </meta_keyword>                                              
                    <meta_description translate="label">
                        <label>Meta Description</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>13</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Meta Description' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </meta_description>                                              
                    <qty translate="label">
                        <label>Qty</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>14</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Qty' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </qty>                                              
                    <manage_stock translate="label">
                        <label>Manage Stock</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Manage Stock' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </manage_stock>                                              
                    <is_in_stock translate="label">
                        <label>Is In Stock</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>16</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Is In Stock' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </is_in_stock>                                              
                    <categories translate="label">
                        <label>Categories</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>17</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Categories' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </categories>                                              
                    <websites translate="label">
                        <label>Websites</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>18</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Websites' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </websites>                                              
                    <image translate="label">
                        <label>Image</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>    
                        <source_model>ng_product/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                        
                        <sort_order>19</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <tooltip>select Enabled for show 'Image' field in add product form.</tooltip>
                    </image>                                              
                </fields>
            </product_settings>   
            <product_credentials_settings translate="label" module="ng_product">
                <label>Credentials Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>                                             
                    <username translate="label">
                        <label>Soap Username</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Enter username of soap api.</comment>
                    </username> 
                    <password translate="label">
                        <label>Soap Password</label>
                        <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Enter password of soap api.</comment>
                    </password> 
                </fields>  
            </product_credentials_settings>     
        </groups>
    </ng_product>
</sections>
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity may indeed be your issue here. If the server is case sensitive and your local machine is not, you can expect this behaviour.

Need to changes files name with capital letters at path `app\code\community\NG\Product\Model\System\Config\Source`

1. Rename file name from `yesno.php` to `Yesno.php`
2. Rename file name from `required.php` to `Required.php`

Also update bellow code in files `Yesno.php` & `Required.php`

```
class NG_Product_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Enabled')),
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Disabled')),
        );
    }
}
```

File `Required.php`

```
class NG_Product_Model_System_Config_Source_Required
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 'name', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Name')),
            array('value' => 'sku', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('SKU')),
            array('value' => 'description', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Description')),
            array('value' => 'short_description', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Short Description')),
            array('value' => 'weight', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Weight')),
            array('value' => 'status', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Status')),
            array('value' => 'url_key', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('URL Key')),
            array('value' => 'visibility', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Visibility')),
            array('value' => 'price', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Price')),
            array('value' => 'tax_class', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Tax Class')),
            array('value' => 'meta_title', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Meta Title')),
            array('value' => 'meta_keyword', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Meta Keywords')),
            array('value' => 'meta_description', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Meta Description')),
            array('value' => 'qty', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Qty')),
            array('value' => 'manage_stock', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Manage Stock')),
            array('value' => 'is_in_stock', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Is In Stock')),
            array('value' => 'categories', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Categories')),
            array('value' => 'websites', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Websites')),
            array('value' => 'image', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ng_product')->__('Image')),
        );
    }
}
```